# Tomcat 8 won't start in Eclipse Luna on Mac Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: java, eclipse

It keeps giving me the same error:

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at /Servers/Tomcat v8.0
>   Server at localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or
>   incomplete.

Tomcat runs fine if I start it from the command line.

I installed Tomcat exactly as instructed on [here](https://code.google.com/p/gbif-providertoolkit/wiki/TomcatInstallationMacOSX). I did not do step 7, and everything up to and including 6 works fine. I have Eclipse Luna version 4.4.1 and Tomcat 8.0.23. All my Tomcat files are at ~/Library/Tomcat

What I did after installation:
1. Started Eclipse
2. Clicked on the Servers tab and clicked the link to create a new server.
3. Selected 'Tomcat v8.0 Server' and clicked Finish
4. Receive an error:

> Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at conf. The configuration may be > corrupt or incomplete

5. Clicked OK and the server is listed anyway.
6. Clicked Finish.
7. R-Clicked on the server and clicked Start.
8. Received the same error.

Comment: You may want to include the OS version. As a side note, I am using T8 on Windows 7 via Eclipse Luna

Comment: Read this thread. It's related to your question .  Simply googled it https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/796069/

Comment: You'll want to give us some further information: where is Tomcat installed? How did you install it? What command line are you using? How are you trying to start it?

Comment: I use the sysdeo TomcatPlugin for eclipse to start my tomcat. Using TOmcat 8 with Eclipse Luna. Just to give an alternative: http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html